# Syntax error in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Java script

```
$('#senurl').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/Coupon1/Reject",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  "id="+@Model.id+"&url="+@url

    });
});
```

> ReferenceError: Expired is not defined
>   [Break On This Error]
>   data:  "id="+2925+"&url="+Expired

Comment: Provided code sample seems ok, error is somewhere else

Comment: I can't see when you use `Expired` variable. Is that your complete source code?

Comment: The problem should be obvious: `@url` seems to be replaced by `Expired` (by the server), which does not seem to be an existing variable. I assume you want to treat it as a string: `+"&url=@url"`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want (but see also below):

```
$('#senurl').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/Coupon1/Reject",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  "id=@Model.id&url=@url"

    });
});
```

...because you have to think about what the *browser* sees, and if `@url` gets replaced with `Expired` by the server, from the error you can tell that what the browser sees for your code is:

```
data: "id="+2925+"&url="+Expired // <=== What the browser sees with your current code
```

Even better, let jQuery handle any potential URI-encoding needed by passing it an object instead:

```
$('#senurl').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/Coupon1/Reject",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  {id: @Model.id, url: "@url"}
    });
});
```

If you don't want to pass jQuery an object and let it handle the URI-encoding for you, then you'll want to handle it yourself:

```
data:  "id=@Model.id&url=" + encodeURIComponent("@url")
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#senurl').click(function () {

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Admin/Coupon1/Reject",
    dataType: "json",
data: "{id:'" + @Model.id + "', 'url': " + @url + "}",  
   success: function (response) {
    alert( response.d); 
},
error: function (data) {
    alert(data);
},
failure: function (msg) {

}
});
```

});

Try this it is working fine. If you are using url routing then you might get some other error.
so better get the respone output and check..

Answer (score -1):

I think its because @url variable is assigned data `Expired` without quotes.

Comment: I think its because @url variable is assigned  data Expired without quotes.

Comment: Yes... so why don't you have it in your answer? :)